# I want to take the values from the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th column and create a one column list

Tags: python

Below you can find the python script

```
def extract_values(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    """Extract values from the second, third, and fourth columns of a file."""
    with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
        lines=input_file.readlines()[2:]
        values_column2=[]
        values_column3=[]
        values_column4=[]
        for line in lines:
            colunms=line.split()
            values_column2.append(columns[1])
            values_column3.append(columns[2])
            values_column4.append(columns[3])

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
        for value2, value3, value4 in zip(values_column2, values_column3, values_column4):
            output_file.write(f"{value2}\n{value3}\n{value4}\n")

input_file_path="file3.xyz"
output_file_path="v1.txt"
extract_and_write_values(input_file_path, output_file_path)
print(f"Values have been extracted and written to {output_file_path}.")
```

I got SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line "output_file.write(f"{value2}\n{value3}\n{value4}\n")"

I try to get a list by extracting the values from column2, column3, and column4. I get the error.

Comment: `extract_values()` is not the same function as `extract_and_write_values()`. Did you perhaps change the name of the function during development and inadvertently call an old version?

Comment: I changed the extract_values to extract_and_write_values to have them the same. But I get the same error

Comment: There is a typo in `colunms=line.split()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed, the typo was the problem ':)